# qemu/kvm file/block disk device types - and iothreads

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, qemu

On a CentOS 7 host, I'm creating a VM from an Amazon Linux 2 qcow2 image:

- Download Amazon Linux 2 cloud-init image (.qcow2 format)
- Copy this file, run `qemu-img resize` to expand it to 40G
- Define it in my VM using `<disk type='file'>` and `<source file='my_resized_file.qcow2'>`

This works - but I'm running ~30 VMs on this host, all running quite heavy Docker workloads - and the disk IO isn't good enough.

I want to try using `iothreads`, `cache=none` and `io=native` as a number of posts online indicate improved performance for SSDs and high-CPU count hosts with these settings. I have plenty of CPU to spare.

I've tried simply adding `iothreads=1` to the domain and `iothread=1` to the disk, but this fails with the error `IOThreads not supported for this QEMU`. I presume this is because I'm using `disk type=file` rather than `disk type=block`.

I would like to:

- Use the OS image, and its cloud-init functions
- Have 40G available to the VM
- Use raw file type, `iothreads`, `cache=none` and `io=native` for maximum performance

My question is therefore...

How do I get my qcow2 OS image to become a 40G raw block device that I can use with these parameters?

Comment: [`qemu-img`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/qemu-img)? Should be something like `qemu-img convert -O raw /path/to/image.qcow2 /path/to/image.bin`.

Comment: Thanks @mforsetti. I've done that bit - and it works. In my latest iteration, I'm using a raw image: `<driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' aio='native'/>`. This still doesn't work with `iothreads` though.

Comment: seems like your libvirt guesses that your QEMU [doesn't support](https://github.com/libvirt/libvirt/blob/v6.3.0/src/qemu/qemu_process.c#L5192) IOThreads.

Comment: Try running `/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -device virtio-blk-device,help` on your CentOS host.

Comment: I ran `/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm -device virtio-blk-device,help` and the output listed some device options - but no mention of iothreads. I don't know how to interpret this information though - what does this mean?

Comment: your QEMU doesn't support IOThreads, what version is your QEMU? IOThreads is supported in QEMU since 2.0. Probably try installing QEMU from EPEL.

Comment: doh... yup... it's only 1.5!!!! thank you, I'll have a look at the EPEL repo now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert from QCOW2 to RAW image file, use [`qemu-img convert`](https://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/convert-images.html), for example:

```
$ qemu-img convert -O raw /path/to/image.qcow2 /path/to/image.bin
```

---

IOThreads is supported on QEMU since [QEMU 2.0](https://wiki.qemu.org/ChangeLog/2.0#Block_devices_in_system_emulation). QEMU 2.0.0 is available on EPEL, so try to run:

```
# yum -y install epel-release
# yum makecache && yum -y install qemu
```

Comment: Thanks for this @mforsetti, I will award you the green tick shortly :) One last question please - there are tons of packages on EPEL, but none of them are called `qemu-kvm`. I can see `qemu.x86_64 2:2.0.0-1.el7.6` and `qemu-common.x86_64 2:2.0.0-1.el7.6` but would these overwrite the `qemu-kvm` I've got installed?

Comment: I read somewhere that I could use the `qemu-kvm-ev` variant instead, which replaces my `qemu-kvm` package and has a newer (`2.9` I think?) version of QEMU. Would you recommend that instead?

Comment: installing `qemu` requires `qemu-kvm-common`, but also replaces your current `qemu-system-x86` to newer versions. EPEL is compatible with base CentOS repository, so you don't need to worry if you're *replacing* your older QEMU.

Comment: about `qemu-kvm-ev`, it's [Virtualization SIG](https://wiki.centos.org/SpecialInterestGroup/Virtualization) variant of QEMU, analog to [RHEV](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/virtualization/enterprise-virtualization). To use that repo, do `yum -y install centos-release-qemu-ev && yum makecache`, then install `qemu-kvm-ev` variant rather than `qemu-kvm`. Virtualization SIG did indeed provides newer QEMU versions, compared to EPEL.

Comment: Thank you! One last question - do you know if the `blk-mq` scheduler has been backported into CentOS kernel `3.10`? Or would it make sense to use the EPEL repo to upgrade to a newer kernel version to access that? Sorry if this is beyond the scope of your expertise or this question.

Comment: nope, I don't know about that, but EPEL doesn't provide new kernel versions.

Comment: I think it does: https://elrepo.org/linux/kernel/el7/x86_64/RPMS/ ? But thank you anyway, this has been very useful to me.

Comment: RHEL did [backport](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html-single/7.2_release_notes/index#storage) `blk-mq` to kernel 3.10.0-327 on [release 7.2](https://access.redhat.com/articles/3078#RHEL7), and CentOS should have it already.